# Is it possible to keep recently blocks only in blockchain

Tags: blockchain

I am curiously to know can old blocks be removed from a a private blockchain, like Ethereum.

For example, the system have 10 blocks

B1 -> B2 -> B3 -> B4 -> B5 -> B6 -> B7 -> B8 -> B9 -> B10

In some reason, I need to erase top 5 order blocks and keep only the recent blocks.

B6 -> B7 -> B8 -> B9 -> B10

I think this would be a common requirement because we don't have infinite storage in most case. Is there any blockchain system supports this?

Answer (score 1):

Blocks means state changes. Every blockchain has a genesis block. And they set their first state in the genesis block. The other blocks just changes the state.

So, you can take state at B6 and use it as your genesis block. And run B7 -> B8 -> B9 -> B10.

Is it an enough answer for your question?

Comment: Thanks. What I am thinking is the same to you. That uses a manual script to create another blockchain with new genesis. But we still have other issue about the smart contract. If a smart contract is bundled in B3, then we have to create new smart contract in the following block which will change the smart contract address. This may be a further research topic in academic.